# Want MBR install of Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation, macintosh, mbr

There's a video driver problem with GPT, the Apple [A1286 Mid-2010 MacBook Pro](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) machines, and NVIDIA GT330M drivers, and running Nouveau has its own problems, so I want to install Cinnamon Mint 19.1 using MBR partitioning so I can use the proprietary drivers. It will be the sole OS on this PC.

I had formatted the internal HDD from a LiveUSB generated by Rufus for MBR, but Mint 19.1 wants to repartition using GPT. How do I install Mint 19.1 and retain the MBR partition table?

Comment: Out of curiosity: does the GPT partition table really cause a video driver problem? GPT is just a disk partitioning scheme. I can see how UEFI (as opposed to legacy BIOS) might cause a video driver incompatibility, but that is a different thing. Mint probably wants to re-partition using GPT to be able to boot using the UEFI firmware.

Comment: Yes, it really does, only on MacBook Pro machines. Gotta go MBR.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It makes no sense to me. I tried to search the net for this, but found nothing. [This](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/) page talks a lot about booting Macs, but does not say MBR is required. It **does** mention that for good graphics performance on Linux you may need BIOS compatibility, and MBR as a consequence of that. The BIOS compatibility is the important thing here, and I'm pretty sure Mint won't object to MBR once you have switched to BIOS compatibility mode.

Comment: Found the explanation of why MBR needed after a pretty long search, lost it, will find it again and add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed OK on the MBR-partitioned drive in this [2010 MacBook Pro A1286](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) once I

- deleted the ext4 partition sda1 which had the entire drive
- created a 1MB partition at the front as sda1 for MBR use. Then,
- created an ext4 partition sda2 for the rest of the drive for root.

Now, Mint 19.1 install is complete, and I can work on the NVIDIA driver issue, serely confident that no other Apple strangeness will complicate this install. {/sarcasm}

Comment: OM, need MBR, not GPT. 73 & best regards.